# Spring Config: Inject the content of file to a property

Tags: spring

Is there anyway to inject the content of a file into a configuration property?

I mean, I've a configuration file like `application.yml`

```
config_param: <the content of file /etc/token>
```

Is there anyway to inject this content into `config_param`?

**EDIT**

This is my `bootstrap.yml` content:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${configserver_url}
      headers:
        X-Config-Token: file:${vault_token_location}
```

where `vault_token_location` contains a file path. So, the content of this file has to be populated into `X-Config-Token`.

Comment: can you post an example @user

Comment: I've added some detail sinto post.